# Windows 7 - Multiple monitors (cloned display) configuration is messed up

Tags: windows-7, display, multiple-monitors

I have Windows 7 in a Dell 15z with a LG TV working as secondary monitor. Some time today, my configuration was messed up by a video running in VLC while disconnecting the HDMI cable.

Now I can't plug my TV in a cloned configuration.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

**Note**: The monitor with number 2 in the first screenshot doesn't really exist.

**Note 2:** The TV works in every other configuration (extended desktop or only the external monitor). And this is a problem in Windows not in the TV to the HDMI cable. Check the screenshots and note the [1|2] monitors in first screenshot (clonned display config) and the second (extended desktop) and compare it.

**Note 3:** I have a hybrid graphic card in my system an Intel HD video card and Nvidea video card with optimus.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Reboot with the LG tv disconnected.  Then re-connect it and try again.

Comment: no success --- :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use <kbd>Windows+P</kbd> with your TV plugged in to switch to dual mode.

Problem was solved in Chat - User had Hybrid Intel/Nvidia Graphics and OPTIMUS was treating the laptop display as 2 monitors, and cloning both of them.

Comment: in cloned configuration the LG TV doesn't turn on, anything else works like a charm

Comment: yeah the TV says "Not signal detected"

Comment: no ,beacause the tv works in extended desktop

Comment: this is a problem in windows maybe in the registry (not the tv or the HDMI cable)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2803/discussion-between-g-koe-and-rafael)

Comment: Problem was solved in Chat - User had Hybrid Intel/Nvidia Graphics and OPTIMUS was treating the laptop display as 2 monitors, and cloning both of them.